# Non-Static initializer blocks - do I have a bit more control?

Tags: java

I am still on a learning curve in Java. To understand a bit more of initializer blocks I created a small test class:

```
public class Script {

    {
        Gadgets.log("anonymous 1");
    }

    public Script() {
        Gadgets.log("constructor");
    }

    {
        Gadgets.log("anonymous 2");
    }
}
```

When I create an instance, I get this log:

```
Script: anonymous 1
Script: anonymous 2
Script: constructor
```

This tells me, both initializer blocks run BEFORE the constructor, in the order they appear in the source code (same as static initializers).
What I want to know is: Do I have a little more control over this behavior?
Because Java Documentation says ([source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html)):

> Initializer blocks for instance variables look just like static
>   initializer blocks, but without the static keyword:

```
{
     // whatever code is needed for initialization goes here 
}
```

> The Java compiler copies initializer blocks into every constructor. Therefore,
>   this approach can be used to share a block of code between multiple
>   constructors.

So what exactly does "copies initializer blocks into every constructor" mean? According to my log, it seems, they are copied *at the beginning* of each constructor. Is this right?

Sharing such blocks between multiple constructors would also make perfectly sense, if they were copied to the END of each constructor (that's what I expected in my anonymous 2).
Is there a way to control those blocks a bit more or is my only option the "classic" way of writing a named method that gets called in every constructor if I want to do common tasks at the *end* of each constructor?

Comment: What is the problem with the code being copied before the constructor rather than after?

Comment: I would expect that it is required they execute before the code in your constructors, and definitely not at the end, because it's entirely reasonable that the constructors can rely on variables having been initialized already.

Comment: Actually, *initialization blocks* are **copied** into the constructor and execute after `super` but before the rest of the constructor bodies.

Comment: You still need constructors because you might have to pass some values during initialization.

Comment: I think both are very reasonable - the beginning _and_ the end. At the beginning to initialize stuff for the constructor and at the end to do things _with_ the stuff that has been passed to the constructor as parameters.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A constructor executes in the following order:

1. `super()` call, implicit or explicit.
2. Variable initializers and initializer blocks, in the order they appear in the source code.
3. Remainder of the constructor.

This is specified in the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5) and cannot be altered.

If a `this()` call is present it replaces (1) and (2).

Comment: Thank you very much. After seing my log, I was expecting that I do not have more control over this. Now I know it.